# SQL select command and vb code for selecting specific rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, select

I got a database with main departments and sub departments (that related to their main departments)  and I want to add option to be able to choose only the rows of specific main department or go even more specific and choose the rows of specific main department and only 1 of its sub departments.

The problem: I also want to have a default option to show all departments rows (for first page load + if user didnt choose department).

I am using Visual Studio with SQL Server Management Studio.

I thought about using a dropdown list for the main and sub departments and maybe a checkbox for each of those to make it true or false for use but I can't think of a good way to make a term on SQL Server to notice those 2 fields only if they are "marked" for use or maybe there is a better way to do this from the first place?

P.S  The gridview got many more columns with data beside the 2 I talked about.

Answer (score 0):

In sql server create a stored procedure with parameters for MainDepartment and SubDepartment then the set the where part of the select statement to be

```
WHERE (@MainDepartment IS NULL Or @MainDepartment = MainDepartmentCol) and (@SubDepartment  IS NULL Or @SubDepartment  = SubDepartmentCol)
```

In your .Net code simply set @MainDepartment or @SubDepartment to NULL depending on whether you want to filter on them or not